# Finding node paths

Tags: python, pathfinding

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas for improving the  following. Personally I am 'happy' with it, apart from the first `for` loop. I  was thinking of another way of writing this, but perhaps it is ok.

```
def findnodepaths(nodepaths, graph, *nodes):

# nodepaths == list()
# graph == defaultdict(set)
# *nodes == 'foo','bar',... possible items in the graph

    nodeset = set(nodes) & set(graph.keys())

# nodeset == nodes that are in the graph ... avoids try / if 

    nodepaths = [(nodeA,weight,nodeB) for nodeA in nodeset for (nodeB,weight) in graph[nodeA]]

    for path in nodepaths:
# for every item in list
        *xs, nodeA = path
# nodeA == last value added, xs == all the rest
        for (nodeB,weight) in graph[nodeA]:
# search again ... just like we all ready have
            if nodeB not in xs:
# if new val not in the triple / quadruple ...
                nodepaths.append( path + (weight,nodeB) )
# add new item to list based on its match
# repeat until no new paths can be found

    return nodeset, nodepaths
# return nodes that were found + all of their paths
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def findnodepaths(nodepaths, graph, *nodes):
```

By python convention, you should really separate the words with underscores. i.e. `find_node_paths`. I'd also wonder if it makes sense to take *nodes, rather then expecting a list to be sent in.

```
# nodepaths == list()
```

Its not clear why you pass this in, rather then just make it here

```
# graph == defaultdict(set)
# *nodes == 'foo','bar',... possible items in the graph
```

This sort of documentation should be in a doctoring, not comments

```
    nodeset = set(nodes) & set(graph.keys())
```

`set(graph.keys()) == set(graph)`, although you may prefer to be explicit.

```
# nodeset == nodes that are in the graph ... avoids try / if 

    nodepaths = [(nodeA,weight,nodeB) for nodeA in nodeset for (nodeB,weight) in graph[nodeA]]
```

I'd store a path as a list, not a tuple.

```
    for path in nodepaths:
# for every item in list
```

That's not a very helpful comment, the syntax already told me that.

```
        *xs, nodeA = path
# nodeA == last value added, xs == all the rest
```

consider renaming your variable rather then using comments

```
        for (nodeB,weight) in graph[nodeA]:
```

Parens are unnecessary

```
# search again ... just like we all ready have
```

Again, noisy comment

```
            if nodeB not in xs:
# if new val not in the triple / quadruple ...
                nodepaths.append( path + (weight,nodeB) )
```

You shouldn't be modifying lists currently having a for loop operating on them. Its considered bad style

```
# add new item to list based on its match
# repeat until no new paths can be found

    return nodeset, nodepaths
# return nodes that were found + all of their paths
```

I'd write this as a recursive function:

```
def _findnodepaths(graph, path, weights):
    for node, weight in graph[path[-1]]:
        if node not in path:
            yield _findnodepaths(graph, path + [node], weights + [node])
    yield path

def findnodepaths(graph, nodes):
    nodeset = set(nodes) & set(graph)
    subgraph = dict( (key, value) for key, value in graph.items())

    nodepaths = []
    for key in graph:
        nodepaths.extend(_findnodepaths(subgraph, [key], [])
    return nodeset, node paths
```

Whether that's better or not is subjective, I think it shows the algorithm better.

Comment: thanks for the break down. I must admit the documentation was only for this site. I'm interested in your comment about modifying lists while working on them. That part made me happy :) ... is it a purely stylistic guide? Agree about the list being passed in. I have changed that already. Thank you for the re-write. It is fascinating seeing how others would approach a problem. Algorithm wise, does it seem ok though?

Comment: one question: why are you creating a subgraph? if the graph contains 1000 keys, this is a bit pointless no? am i missing something?

Comment: @user969617, adding to the list works in the current implementation, but I believe no guarantees are made that it will always work. I figured the subgraph might simplify the code a bit, but it didn't really work out that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have no way to test this, but is this what you are looking for?

```
def findnodepaths(nodepaths, graph, *nodes):

    nodeset = set(nodes) & set(graph.keys())
    nodepaths = [(nodeA,weight,nodeB) for nodeA in nodeset
        for (nodeB,weight) in graph[nodeA]]

    newnp = [path + (weight,nodeB) for path in nodepaths
        for (nodeB,weight) in graph[nodeA] if nodeB not in path[::-1][1:]]

    return nodeset, (nodepaths + newnp)
```

Comment: Very nearly. The for loop that I use `for path in nodepaths` effectively creates a loop, that constantly updates the `nodepaths` until it can not find any more links in the graph (a dictionary). I was wondering how if this for loop could be written any other way?